# Is there a simple way to query the top URLs in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, api, analytics-api

I'm looking for an easy way to query GA programmatically in order to display the most popular pages on my site.

GA has a Data Export API, but it seems kind of complex to work with for what I want to do. Is there a simpler way or am I stuck with the Data Export API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Export API really is the simplest way to get the data from Google Analytics although you have more options - and more comprehensive data, given that Google Analytics does not track spiders or users with Javascript disabled - if you parse your own server logs.

The [Data Export API Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/1.0/gdataProtocol.html) page includes instructions which you can test on the command line with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (as well as links to [Javascript, Java, and Python interface libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/mgmtLibraries.html)) and it appears as though there is also a [PHP interface library](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) at Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [embeddedanalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  You could define a report of your most popular pages and then embed the chart into your website.

We are also working on a "Top Content" widget which will have clickable links for your most popular pages.

(disclosure: this is a site I have developed)